# Cannot create wordpress web app in azure with Terraform

Tags: wordpress, azure, terraform

I am trying to create wordpress web application on Azure with Terraform. Each web app has own database. I manage to create resource groups, database server and databases but i cannot create wordpress web app. I can create a web app and all works fine but not wordpress. When i make wordpress web app manually and import data to see what is different i see that wordpress has repo_url and branch pointing to wordpress-azure repo on github. When i try to incorporate this in code i get error message.

```
resource "azurerm_mysql_database" "testtt" {
  name                = "testtt"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.RG_mok_2024.name
  server_name         = azurerm_mysql_server.wp-db-mok-2024.name
  charset             = "utf8"
  coll`enter code here`ation           = "utf8_unicode_ci"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "testtt" {
  name                = "testtt"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.RG_mok_2024.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.RG_mok_2024.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.appserviceplan-wordpress-mok-6.id

  site_config {
    dotnet_framework_version = "v4.0"
    scm_type                 = "GitHub"
    default_documents =  ["Default.htm","Default.html","Default.asp","index.htm","index.html","iistart.htm","default.aspx","index.php","hostingstart.html"]

  }

  source_control {
    repo_url = "https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/wordpress-azure"
    branch = "master"
  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "defaultConnection"
    type  = "MySQL"
    value = "Database=testtt;Data Source=wp-db-mok-2024.mysql.database.azure.com;User Id=mysqladminun@wp-db-mok-2024;Password=password"
  }
}
```

The error message i get when i am using source_control part of a code is
    Error: "source_control": this field cannot be set

Answer (score 3):

The source_control field is only exported. It cannot be used to connect a deploymentsource.

To execute an automated deployment directly, there is currently only the workaround via a `local-exec` `null_resource`.
The sourcecontrol integration can be created using an azure cli / powershell script which is then executed by the local-exec provisioner.

This works as follows:

```
resource "null_resource" "scm_integration" { 
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command     = "${path.module}/enable_scm.ps1 -webAppName ${azurerm_app_service.testtt.name} -appResourceGroupName ${azurerm_resource_group.RG_mok_2024.name} -scmBranch master -repoUrl https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/wordpress-azure"
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

In addition you need the powershell script `enable_scm.ps1`.

[In this GitHub Issue the workaround incl. script is described completely](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/1104#issuecomment-424242437)

Answer (score 0):

According to [terraform doc about azurerm app service](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html), the field source_control is only exported. And it is ONLY exported when the scm_type is set to LocalGit. You have set it to *GitHub*, and it is an output value, so according to the documentation, you dont need that.

Furthermore in line 6 there is `enter code here` but I guess that this was pasted here by accident.

Finally, I hope that in the connection string value, your database password is not "password".

Comment: Thanks. Password is not password it was just placeholder. This was proof of concept how i am trying to do stuff. Is there any way to tell terraform that my web app is wordpress web app? If i make wordpress web app manually i get External Repository Project
:
https://github.com/azureappserviceoss/wordpress-azure but if i make web app with terraform i get web app but not wordpress. Is there any way to tell terraform to create wordpress web application?

Comment: I have never used wordpress on azure. I guess you are mixing up the application and the infrastructure. Terraform helps you creating the infrastructure. This is for example the database, the webhost, network settings, loadbalancer, firewalls, all that stuff. To my knowledge, wordpress is more of an application. You have to install it on your infrastructure. There are other tools to do that. e.g. ansible. But if I see it correctly, microsoft has a marketplace for web apps. Perhaps you can just select wordpress there, and let it deploy on your architecture autmagically? But I am guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to set the `source_control` section before the `site_config`?  There is an open issue for the Terraform azurerm_app_service provider that suggests this might be a work-around.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3696